# memory pools: will they improve cache usage for structs larger than the cache line size?

Tags: c++, caching

As I understand it, memory pools should improve cache performance for objects commonly accessed together, if the objects are smaller than the cache line size - because then adjacent objects will likely be fetched into the cache at the same time.

But what about objects larger than the cache line size?  Is there any benefit to pooling such data into the same region of memory?

(Assuming that allocation/deallocation times are insignificant, it's access I'm worried about...)

Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about _the_ cache line size. Most systems have multi-level caches with different cache line sizes. Also, main memory is organized in pages, and a page which isn't actively accessed is powered down a bit. I.e. even main memory benefits from locality of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory pooling makes sense if your app uses a **huge** amount of memory and starts to swap. Then, if the objects lie adjacent to each other, they will be paged in and out together.

Comment: I'm marking this definitive - while Kerrick's answer is true, it is really about allocation/deallocation which doesn't bother me.  MSalters comment is relevant too.  But in general I concluded that access will only be significantly faster in the case you highlight here.

Comment: As a footnote, I did find another use for pools: they mean that pointers tend to be allocated in strictly increasing order of address.  This greatly speeds up a routine I have which builds a large stl::set of objects indexed by their pointers, as a heap insert hint can then be used.  (The objects are also indexed by another field, but that happens to be equal for all of them at heap creation time).

Answer (score 6):

One important reason for using pools is that they make for a much simpler allocation scheme than a general-purpose allocator. Since all objects have the same size, there's no fragmentation, and you just need to maintain a free list. For a new allocation, you try to pop off the top of the free list, or if the list is empty you increment the high watermark, done. (You can implement the free list in O(1) space inside the pool memory itself.)

However, the use of pools is highly situational, and whether there's any benefit depends very much on your actual code path and allocation requirements. The modern standard allocator is already very good with many short-lived fixed-size allocations, so you really need to profile and check.

Answer (score 0):

My previous project was an embedded app with built-in webserver for ARM SAM9x platform. It has only 64K heap, and does not have any console/display or filesystem, so there's no way to just *printf()* an error to *stderr* or log it to file. Altough, it must work 7/24 there's it should not stop with "out of memory" error, it **must** run without error. If it's started once, it would never stop. Out of memory is not a recoverable error, it's the complete fail of the system.

So, I decided not to use **new**. I've been used object arrays: ringbuffers, fixed-size pools, etc. - and it just works. Java (and C# etc.) makes us wrong, these modern languages say, that memory is a big ocean, which anyone can dip from. Yep, it's true, if you have plenty, but the cost is high, just as you brought up in this post.

Try it! Use as few *new* (and *malloc()*, of course), just as possible. A nice side effect: you have not to use *delete* (and *free()*), there would be no memory leak problems.

Comment: this is not an answer to his question.

Comment: The question is about mem alloc optimizing, I just added another approach.

Comment: it is not about memory allocation optimization, it is about memory _access_ optimization, which is an entirely different concern, even if it can be obtained by particular allocation disciplines.

Comment: In C++, you can implement `operator new` yourself, even on a class by class basis. Therefore, the use of "fixed-size pools" does not imply that you have to forego `new`. Besides, you _do_ have to use `delete` or an equivalent, even with fixed-size pools. After all, you must return unused memory to the pool or it will exhaust quickly.

Comment: It's a kind of programming *style* not using new/delete in C++. You allocate all objects compile-time. This is a kind of **round** the problems of pool. There are wide range of problems where this method works - and there're also several, where you can't live without allocating objects runtime. *Before* you thinking on pools or own allocator, check this option.